# Copy pre-populated db from /assets

Tags: android

I am using code in [this article](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) to copy a pre-populated db I have into a freshly created db thus overwriting it.

The overwrite is successful. I am able to see the correctly copied db in the right path data/data/my.package/databases/myDatabase. But this is ONLY if I look at the database before leaving getWritableDatabse().

If I leave getWritableDatabse() the db is invalidated: it still keeps its right size BUT it has only the android_metadata instead of my tables that are then all gone.

I didn't manage to get access to the Android source code for Eclipse (followed all the instructions but it still doesn't work) but using [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase%28%29) I managed to narrow down the problem to lines 173-176 in method `getWritableDatabase()`.

```
173 db.setVersion(mNewVersion);
174 db.setTransactionSuccessful();
175 } finally {
176   db.endTransaction();
```

Anyone has a clue why this piece of code might rewrite my db and empty it?

This is the relevant stack:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended)   
StournamentDbAdapter$DatabaseHelper(SQLiteOpenHelper).getWritableDatabase() line: 180   
StournamentDbAdapter.open() line: 192   
ActivityTournamentsList.onCreate(Bundle) line: 57   
ActivityTournamentsList(Activity).performCreate(Bundle) line: 4465  
Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1049   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1920    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1981 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 123    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1147  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4424    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 784  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 551 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

I fist use `mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();` which calls to `DatabaseHelper.onCreate()`where the creation of the db actually happens. In `DatabaseHelper.onCreate()` I call only `copyDatabase();` which looks like this:

```
private void copyDatabase() throws IOException
    {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput =  sContext.getAssets().open(StournamentConstants.Database.DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = StournamentConstants.Database.DB_PATH + StournamentConstants.Database.DATABASE_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0)
        {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }
```

All this goes fine and the db is correctly copied. Only when I climb out of the stack and return to `getWritableDatabase() line: 180` that something goes wrong: the size of the db stays the same but it loses all tables besides the àndroid_metadata`.

---

**Intermediate conclusion**

I dug a bit more into the code (the above mentioned GrepCode site was VERY helpful) because I wanted to get to the bottom of this. After going into `getWritableDatabase()`, on line 165 it will call `onCreate()`, where I replace to database by using `copyDatabase();`. The issue is that before, on `getWritableDatabase() line 162` `db.beginTransaction();` is called. Why is that a problem? I will explain by showing the sequence of events:

1. call `getWritableDatabase()`
2. `getWritableDatabase()` calls `db = SQLiteDatabase.create(null);` hence creating a db
3. `getWritableDatabase()` calls `db.beginTransaction();`
4. `getWritableDatabase()` calls `onCreate()`
5. inside `onCreate()` I replace the database by calling `copyDatabase();` which copies the db from asset to the db location. Not sure why the already created db doesn't crash at that moment. Maybe because there is no lock on it?
6. on line 176 `getWritableDatabase()` calls `db.endTransaction();` which is the crucial part: it is nice and well that I copied my db into the initially created db, BUT when `db.endTransaction();` is called, the system commits all the changes to my newly copied db. But remember: I did no changes, I created no tables - I just copied the db to the correct location. So the commit commits NOTHING thus rewriting the db with NOTHING. **For that I get an empty db**.

I had the evil thought to:

1. Copy the db in `onCreate()`
2. Open the newly copied db and replace the db `getWritableDatabase()` uses (`onCreate()` gets the db as parameter from `getWritableDatabase()`) with it.

Something like that:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    try 
    {               
        copyDatabase();

        String dbPath = StournamentConstants.Database.DB_PATH + StournamentConstants.Database.DATABASE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase activeDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);              

         db = activeDb;
    } 
       catch (IOException e) 
    {
       Log.i(getClass().getName() + ".onCreate ", e.getMessage());
   }   
}
```

The problem with that is that I get an `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked` so I can't get the newly copied db. And besides that - I am not sure what sinister consequences lurk behind such a devious deed.

So I will do what @Barak suggests and move my copying into the constructor - way before the system tries to create the db. So when `getWritableDatabase()` is finally reached, the db is already there and the system will not attempt to touch it. I learned a lot today - am very pleased.

Conclusion: if you can read (code), you have a definite advantage :^)

Will keep you posted on how this worked for me.

---

**Final conclusion**

I solved the issue.

Few differences:

1. I DON'T do it inside `DatabaseHelper`'s constructor. That would have taken too many code changes. Instead I am doing it inside `open()` of my `private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` class
2. I DON'T use `getReadableDatabase()` but `getWritableDatabase()`. The reason is simple: `getReadableDatabase()` will ALWAYS call `getWritableDatabase()` so I thought I save that one...

I also tried to be a wiseguy and instead of calling `getWritableDatabase()` (which has some overhead of code) simply CREATING the db file on my own. I failed. I think it is due to permission issues or something. This is what I tried inside the `copyDatabase()`:

```
File f = new File(DB_PATH);
if (!f.exists()) 
{
    f.mkdir();
}
```

But it always fails. I later found out that `OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);`actually should take care of the file creation.

Hope this helps anyone!

Comment: I do the same thing amenities.works.dine, the problem isn't in the framework.  Post your code.

Comment: Consider using `SQLiteAssetHelper`, which handles the unpack-the-database-from-assets pattern in a reusable component: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: @Barak, added code. Didn't get the amenities.works.dine thing - but it sounds interesting, what did you mean? "Ten remez".

Comment: That was my phone "correcting" me.  I didn't realize it had done it until it was too late to edit it.  :p  That should read "and it works fine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only difference I see is that I don't do the database copying/creation in `onCreate`, that is empty.  I do it all in the constructor, like this:

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context, String dbname, int dbversion) {
        super(context, dbname, null, dbversion);
            if (checkDataBase(dbname)) {
                openDataBase(dbname);
            } else {
                try {
                    this.getReadableDatabase();
                    copyDataBase(dbname);
                    this.close();
                    openDataBase(dbname);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                     throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
                Toast.makeText(context,"Initial " + dbname + " database has been created",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
      }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, the embarrassing stuff phones today can write on their own is [pretty amazing](http://www.damnyouautocorrect.com/4077/10-most-popular-autocorrects-from-december-2010/) :). When I try calling `this.close();` after `copyDataBase(dbname);` inside `onCreate()` it crashes my application because apparently my main activity is using it. I thought the right way to do this is to do it in `onCreate()` because it takes care of checking if the DB is open/existing etc. I will try to rewrite my code an we see...