# Cannot Copy DB from assets/ in SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-assets

I have a pre-populated DB that I've created offline and put in the `assets/` directory. I'm trying to copy it when `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate()` is called, but I'm running into serious trouble.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    importAssets();
}
```

When I write my code like this, I consistently get a **no such table** error when subsequently trying to get data out of the database. I did some mucking around and started inserting SQL statements into `onCreate()` as well as the call to `importAssets()`, for example:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    importAssets();
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE main_table (some_col);");
}
```

Now when I run the app, I get problems with a **column not found** error (the above schema doesn't match what the DB access code expects, it's missing a number of columns. On the second run of the app, `android_metatdata` get corrupted and then it all goes to hell. I've also tried with the SQL code before the `importAssets()` call, with similarly disasterous results.

So I'm starting to think that the file copy I'm doing in `importAssets()` is essentially getting truncated by `onCreate()`. Am I right? Is the only way to create a DB in `onCreate()` by directly using SQL? Can I not use this function to copy a ready-made DB from `assets/`?

I have confirmed that `importAssets()` is running correctly by using `Log()` calls. Here is the complete function:

```
private void importAssets() throws IOException
{  
    AssetManager am = mCtx.getAssets();
    InputStream in = am.open(DB_NAME);
    FileOutputStream out;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    File db;

    db = new File(DB_DIR + "/" + DB_NAME);

    // copy the DB from assets to standard DB dir created above
    out = new FileOutputStream(db);
    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();
    if (!db.exists())
    {
        Log.e(TAG, DB_DIR + "/" + DB_NAME + " does not exist");
    }
}
```

I've seen [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10926456/46461) the suggestion that I do the file copy inside the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor, but that means I'd have to manually check the presence of the file in `importAssets()` since the constructor gets called every time I use the DB. Also, `onCreate()` would be effectively useless for what I want to do, though I don't see any way to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm now convinced that my suspicion was right. The `onCreate()` function of `SQLiteOpenHelper` will create the DB file, specified in the `name` parameter of the call to the super class constructor. It then expects you to modify this DB file (add tables, data, alter tables, etc) from within the `onCreate()` function using the various DB libraries. **Copying a file from somewhere else will just get truncated**.

I don't know how or why it's doing this, but this makes `onCreate()` useless for 'creating' a DB by copying it intact from `assets/` which is what I need. I've moved `importAssets()` to the constructor and added the appropriate check to not overwrite it if it's already there. With nothing in `onCreate()` at all it doesn't seem to disrupt what's going on elsewhere.

I think that `SQLiteOpenHelper` really needs the capability to run an SQLite script. This way I don't have to hard-code long chunks of SQL into my Java code, when all I really want to do is get a DB setup.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer led me to the solution. I basically did 3 things and it was all done in the constructor and only if the dbFile didn't exist (where `dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME)`), 1st was to call `dbFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()` then `dbFile.createNewFile()` and in the end copy the DB from the assets.